# How to store linux apps on my bootable linux pendrive?

Tags: linux, boot, apt

I use bootable linux(ubuntu 15.04). Everytime I boot linux using my pendrive, I have to download apps. After I remove my Drive ,the apps are uninstalled.
Is there any way to store these apps on the same pendrive so that I dont have to download them whenever I boot Linux?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question I think you need to install Ubuntu on your pendrive as "persistent." I will then retain installed apps, bookmarks etc.